# Why do we bypass instance attributes during implicit lookup of special methods?

Tags: python, function, methods, method-call

From the [‘Special method lookup for new-style classes’ section](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) of the ‘Data model’ chapter in the Python documentation (bold emphasis mine):

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on
> an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary. That behaviour is the reason why the following code raises
> an exception (unlike the equivalent example with old-style classes):
>
> ```
> >>> class C(object):
> ...     pass
> ...
> >>> c = C()
> >>> c.__len__ = lambda: 5
> >>> len(c)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: object of type 'C' has no len()
> ```
>
> **The rationale behind this behaviour lies with a number of special methods such as `__hash__()` and
> `__repr__()` that are implemented by all objects, including type objects. If the implicit lookup of these methods
> used the conventional lookup process, they would fail when invoked on the type object itself:**
>
> ```
> >>> 1 .__hash__() == hash(1)
> True
> >>> int.__hash__() == hash(int)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: descriptor ’__hash__’ of ’int’ object needs an argument
> ```
>
> **Incorrectly attempting to invoke an unbound method of a class in this way is sometimes referred to as ‘metaclass
> confusion’, and is avoided by bypassing the instance when looking up special methods:**
>
> ```
> >>> type(1).__hash__(1) == hash(1)
> True
> >>> type(int).__hash__(int) == hash(int)
> True
> ```

I cannot catch the words in bold well…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what's going on here, you need to have a (basic) understanding of the conventional attribute lookup process. Take a typical introductory object-oriented programming example - `fido` is a `Dog`:

```
class Dog(object):
    pass

fido = Dog()
```

If we say `fido.walk()`, the first thing Python does is to look for a function called `walk` in `fido` (as an entry in `fido.__dict__`) and call it with no arguments - so, one that's been defined something like this:

```
def walk():
   print "Yay! Walking! My favourite thing!"

fido.walk = walk
```

and `fido.walk()` will work. If we hadn't done that, it would look for an attribute `walk` in `type(fido)` (which is `Dog`) and call it with the instance as the first argument (ie, `self`) - that is triggered by the usual way we define methods in Python:

```
class Dog:
    def walk(self):
         print "Yay! Walking! My favourite thing!"
```

Now, when you call `repr(fido)`, it ends up calling the special method `__repr__`. It might be (poorly, but illustratively) defined like this:

```
class Dog:
    def __repr__(self):
          return 'Dog()'
```

But, the bold text is saying that it also makes sense to do this:

```
 repr(Dog)
```

Under the lookup process I just described, the first thing it looks for is a method called `__repr__` assigned to `Dog`... and hey, look, there is one, because we just poorly but illustratively defined it. So, Python calls:

```
Dog.__repr__()
```

And it blows up in our face:

```
>>> Dog.__repr__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    Dog.__repr__()
TypeError: __repr__() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

because `__repr__()` expects a `Dog` instance to be passed to it as its `self` argument. We could do this to make it work:

```
class Dog:
    def __repr__(self=None):
       if self is None:
           # return repr of Dog
       # return repr of self
```

But, then, we would need to do this *every time* we write a custom `__repr__` function. That it needs to know how to find the `__repr__` of the class is a problem, but not much of a one - it can just delegate to `Dog`'s own class (`type(Dog)`) and call its `__repr__` with `Dog` as its `self`-argument:

```
 if self is None:
   return type(Dog).__repr__(Dog)
```

But first, this breaks if the classname changes in the future, since we've needed to mention it twice in the same line. But the bigger problem is that this is basically going to be boilerplate: 99% of implementations will just delegate up the chain, or forget to and hence be buggy. So, Python takes the approach described in those paragraphs - `repr(foo)` skips finding an `__repr__` attached to `foo`, and goes straight to:

```
type(foo).__repr__(foo)
```

Comment: Good! But how to understand `1 .__hash__()` is ok while `int.__hash__()` is not? I think `1` and `int` are both instances of their types (`1` from `int`, `int` from `type`). This inconsistency makes me crazy...x x

Comment: @ymfoi for the same reason that `Dog.__hash__()` doesn't work: `int.__hash__` doesn't know how to hash `int` itself, only how to hash instances of int, and it expects to be given an instance of int as `self`. To hash int itself, we need `type.__hash__(int)`.

Comment: well, it's strange that `1 .__hash__()` does know how to do the hash thing --- to invoke `int.__hash__`. But why does not `int.__hash__()` know it can use `type.__hash__(int)`?

Comment: @ymfoi because the lookup rules for `1 .__hash__` say that an `__hash__` directly on `1` takes precedence if it exists - it doesn't exist, so Python looks for `__hash__` on `int`, which does exist, so it uses it. For `int.__hash__`, the one on `int` does exist, so it picks that one.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to remember is that classes are instances of their **metaclass**. Some operations need to be performed not just on instances, but on types as well. If the method on the instance was run then it would fail since the method on the instance (really a class in this case) would require an instance of the class rather than the metaclass.

```
class MC(type):
  def foo(self):
    print 'foo'

class C(object):
  __metaclass__ = MC
  def bar(self):
    print 'bar'

C.foo()
C().bar()
C.bar()
```

Comment: ..hmm..could you plz use that int and type(int) to make an example?

Answer (score 1):

Normal attribute retrieval `obj.attr` looks up `attr` in the *instance* attributes and *class* attributes of `obj`. It is defined in `object.__getattribute__` and `type.__getattribute__`.

Implicit special method call `special(obj, *args, **kwargs)` (e.g. `hash(1)`) looks up `__special__` (e.g. `__hash__`) in the class attributes of `obj` (e.g. `1`), *bypassing the instance attributes* of `obj` instead of performing the normal attribute retrieval `obj.__special__`, and calls it. The rationale is that the instance attributes of `obj` may require a receiver argument (usually called `self`) which is an instance of `obj` *to be called* (e.g. function attributes) whereas `special(obj, *args, **kwargs)` does not provide one, contrary to the class attributes of `obj` which may require a receiver argument (usually called `self`) which is an instance of the class `type(obj)` *to be called* (e.g. function attributes) and `special(obj, *args, **kwargs)` provides one: `obj`.

### Example

The special method `__hash__` takes a single argument. Compare these two expressions:

```py
>>> 1 .__hash__
<method-wrapper '__hash__' of int object at 0x103c1f930>
>>> int.__hash__
<slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'int' objects>
```

- The first expression retrieves the method `vars(type(1))['__hash__'].__get__(1)` bound to `1` from the *class* attribute `vars(type(1))['__hash__']`. So the class attribute requires a receiver argument which is an instance of `type(1)` to be called, and we have already provided one: `1`.
- The second expression retrieves the function `vars(int)['__hash__'].__get__(None, int)` from the *instance* attribute `vars(int)['__hash__']`. So the instance attribute requires a receiver argument which is an instance of `int` to be called, and we have not provided one yet.

```py
>>> 1 .__hash__()
1
>>> int.__hash__(1)
1
```

Since the built-in function `hash` takes a single argument, `hash(1)` can provide the `1` required in the first call (a class attribute call) while `hash(int)` cannot provide the `1` required in the second call (an instance attribute call). Consequently, `hash(obj)` should bypass the instance attribute `vars(obj)['__hash__']` and directly access the class attribute `vars(type(obj))['__hash__']`:

```py
>>> hash(1) == vars(type(1))['__hash__'].__get__(1)()
True
>>> hash(int) == vars(type(int))['__hash__'].__get__(int)()
True
```